# How to set up pam_mount?

Tags: mount, samba, automount, pam, kerberos

I am trying to automount SMB shares from a Synology NAS on a client running Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (yes I know it is out of date and plan to upgrade to 20.04.2 soon).  I have tried using autofs, but have problems with user-specific shares, which don't get remapped when one user logs out and another logs in and are therefore inaccessible to the second user, necessitating a reboot (see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253693/how-can-ad-users-on-ubuntu-client-seamlessly-access-files-and-folders-on-synolog/1336970?noredirect=1#comment2282433_1336970) for details). After further research it seems that pam_mount might provide the solution, since it is said to automatically mount and unmount volumes at the beginning and end of each session. Unfortunately, I haven't yet found detailed enough instructions for my modest level of Ubuntu / Linux competence. The various sources I have found mention conflicting directories for PAM and its configuration files. The man page is helpful, but leaves a lot to the imagination. Is pam_mount a daemon, like autofs? If so, what (if anything) do I need to do to ensure that it runs (beyond installing libpam-mount)? Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on how to set up pam_mount, including examples?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release, it had *extended* support that was provided by a PPA which has already been deleted (it's unsupported now; https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-May/041449.html) so you're asking us to support a release that reached EOL in 2019.  All Ubuntu 18.04 LTS flavors (exluding Studio which was already EOL) reached EOL April 29, 2019 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/04/27/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-released/)

Comment: As I said, I am planning to upgrade; I don't intend to implement pam_mount until *after* the upgrade, so I would be happy for instructions for 20.04.2

Comment: Well, after you've upgraded and are on-topic for this site, ask your question again.

Comment: I am now running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS.  How about it?