# How to pam_mount server shares?

Tags: login, shared-folders, pam, domain-server

I have a Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 desktop client joined to an AD domain controller, which also serves as a file rver.  I would like to automount server shares on login of any domain user.

1. The [manpage on pam_mount.conf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html) mentions the possibility of per-user configuration files, but what I need is a per group configuration. If I add a  record in /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml with "sgrp" specified, will it then be ignored for logins which do not belong to "sgrp"?
   If not, how can I restrict the mapping to domain users?
2. The [manpage for pam_mount](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/pam_mount.8.html) says that "you must include two entries in the  system's  applicable  /etc/pam.d/service config files". Which files are those? I have 31 service configuration files in /etc/pam.d".  Various posts suggest adding such lines to "gdm", "system-auth", "system-auth-ac" or "system-login", but I have none of these.  Here is what I have:

   chfn            common-auth                    cron      other     runuser    sddm-autologin    sudo
   chpasswd        common-password                cups      passwd    runuser-l  sddm-greeter      sudo-i
   chsh            common-session                 login     polkit-1  samba      sssd-shadowutils  su-l
   common-account  common-session-noninteractive  newusers  ppp       sddm       su
3. How can I debug what pam is doing at login?  I have enabled debug in /etc/security/pam-mount.conf.xml, but this will not help me if it is not executed due to a failure to add it to the correct service nor will it help me to troubleshoot GUI logins. Is there a pam log and, if so, how can I view it?

P.S. AskUbuntu kindly suggests that this may duplicate [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253693/how-can-ad-users-on-ubuntu-client-seamlessly-access-files-and-folders-on-synolog). However, I haven't received any useful response to that and I am trying to be more specific here.

P.P.S. My prime suspects, common-auth and common-session, already contain references to pam-mount, but the desired shares are not being mounted.

Comment: I have meanwhile found entries for pam_mount in /var/auth.log, It appears that pam_mount is being executed via common-auth, which is included in many other pam config files.  The messages in auth.log do not indicate any failure.  Generally, what I see is "nothing to mount".  I can mount one of the configured volumes easily via:
"sudo mount -t cifs -osec=krb5 //myserver/shared_directory /my_local_directory"

Comment: My volume declarations in /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml take the form:

<volume sgrp="MYDOMAIN\domain users" fstype="cifs" server="servername.domain" path="shared_folder_name" mountpoint="local_directory_path" options="sec=krb5,cruid=%(USERUID),noexec,rw,nofail" />
In addition, the file includes the declaration: <mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
I have commented out <mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" /> because I had to create the local directories manually in order to test mounting via mount.cifs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own questions:

1. Mount commands in /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml with "sgrp" specified are, in fact, ignored if they are invoked by a user who doesn't belong to "sgrp".
2. I didn't have to add pam_mount.so lines to *any* of the service configuration files in /etc/pam.d.  They were already present in common-auth, common-password and common-session and these files are included in many of the other service files, which appears to suffice.
3. Enabling debug in /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml resulted in pam-mount output in the relevant logs in /var/log, in my case, auth.log and syslog

The reason why pam-mount didn't work for me at first was the format of the argument sgrp="MYDOMAIN\domain users".  Checking the group membership with the "groups" command led me to realize that it needs to be sgrp="domain users@mydomain".